# Unable to run Papaja in Windows due to spaces in folder name

Tags: r, devtools, papaja

I'm trying to load `papaja` in R (version 3.6.0). I'm running Windows 10 on my computer. When I try to run `devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja")` I get the following error message:

```
 package ‘markdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

 The downloaded binary packages are in
     C:\Users\My 
 Name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKCmBDG\downloaded_packages
     ERROR
    cannot change to directory 'C:\Users\My'
    The system cannot find the path specified.
 Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = 
 TRUE,  : 
   System command error
```

From some research, including [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727058/issue-when-calling-executable-in-a-path-that-has-space) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544345/rscript-file-path-with-space), I realise that this is a common issue, but none of the answers I can find help me work around this in `papaja`.

For info, I don't have this problem when installing other packages using `install.packages()`.

Comment: Hi Catherine, can you install other packages from GitHub (e.g., `install_github("crsh/citr")`?

Comment: Hi, no this won't work either - I get the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This suggests to me that your problem is not specific to `papaja` but probably a more general problem with `devtools::install_github()` when the path contains whitespace. Am I right to assume that the error message relates to the installation of the `markdown` package? Was the package successfully installed nonetheless?

Comment: Ok, so I updated `markdown` and I think it is now working! I need to run a few other things to check (which I will do later this week). Thanks so much (and sorry for the slow response, I have just come back from 2 weeks of holiday)!

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve this problem after hours and hours of googling. The problem is *not* `papaja`; it is the presence of spaces in the path, which `devtools` does not deal with well.

To solve this, I first changed my library path:

`.libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library") # for R v.3.6.1`

At first I couldn't get this to work - I kept getting the error `'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.1/library"' is not writable`. Basically, this is because I did not have permission to write into this folder. To fix this, you simply close RStudio, go to the folder where the programme is saved and right click, then select 'Run as administrator'.